# R syntax to form variance-covariance matrix given the coordinates x and y

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to write R code to use distance between two coordinates x and y for form a variance-covariance matrix. I have try This but could not work for n.

```
M1 <- matrix(c(1, 12, 3, 4, 5), nrow=5, ncol=1)   
M2 <- matrix(c(16, 7, 8, 9, 10), nrow=5, ncol=1) 
n <- length(M2) 
Distance <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=1) 
Di <- function(M1, M2) { 
  for(i in 1:n) { 
    D <- ((M1[i, 1]- M1[1, 1])^2 + (M2[i, 1] - M2[1, 1])^2)
    Distance[i, ] <- c(D) 
    } 
  return(Distance) 
} 
M5 <- Di(M1, M2) 
M5
```

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: I mean add your develop code to question by editing the question not as comment. It is hard to read codes in comment

Comment: I t keeps telling ithe code contain some errors

Comment: How do I add the try? please help

Comment: I added your code in comment to question have a look after changes applied

Comment: The code vcov( as.matrix( dist( x, y)) did not work.

Comment: Please could you add example to vcov( as.matrix( dist( x, y)). Because it did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If A(1, 16), B(12, 7), ..., N(x, y) are coordinates of 2D points then the distance matrix can be calculated as follows :

```
x <- c(1, 12, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(16, 7, 8, 9, 10)

point_coords <- mapply(function(m, n) c(m, n), x, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
point_pairs <- expand.grid(point_coords, point_coords)
point_pairs$dist <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) sqrt((x[1] - y[1]) ^ 2 + (x[2] - y[2]) ^ 2), point_pairs$Var1, point_pairs$Var2)
point_pairs$P1 <- sapply(point_pairs$Var1, function(x) paste(x[[1]], " ", x[[2]]))
point_pairs$P2 <- sapply(point_pairs$Var2, function(x) paste(x[[1]], " ", x[[2]]))
point_pairs <- point_pairs[, -(1:2)]
point_pairs <- point_pairs[, c(2, 3, 1)]
library(reshape2)
point_dists <- dcast(point_pairs, P1 ~ P2)
names(point_dists)[1] <- "P1/P2"
m <- as.matrix(point_dists[-1])
m
```

Output:

```
       1   16    12   7    3   8    4   9   5   10
[1,]  0.000000 14.212670 8.246211 7.615773 7.211103
[2,] 14.212670  0.000000 9.055385 8.246211 7.615773
[3,]  8.246211  9.055385 0.000000 1.414214 2.828427
[4,]  7.615773  8.246211 1.414214 0.000000 1.414214
[5,]  7.211103  7.615773 2.828427 1.414214 0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks all. but what I want is to  combine the x <- c(1, 12, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(16, 7, 8, 9, 10) to form the distance matrix such that x will form the row and y the column to for the matrix ie sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2 -y1)^2)  NOT FOR X T

Comment: Thanks. I'll change an answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem. but not yet working, see the out put Error in library(reshape2) : there is no package called ‘reshape2’ and also error in dcast, no package as dcast. Thanks

Comment: Please use`install.package("reshape2")`  to install package and then l`ibrary(reshape2)` to load the library.

Comment: Thanks Artem, it has work but I want it as a matrix so that I can transpose/invert it ie remove    P1/P2    1   16    12   7    3   8    4   9   5   10
# 1 1   16  
# 2 12   7 
# 3  3   8  
# 4  4   9  
# 5 5   10

Comment: Hi JET, I corrected the answer in accordance to your input

Comment: Good day@Artem. pleaese could you help me with the code on Mean square prediction error (MSPE) and Integrated square error (ISE) of the function f<-function(x,si,th,h,la)
{
y= ((si)^2)*exp(-(h/th)^2)*exp(-(x/th)^2)*exp(-(h/th)^2) - 2*la*exp(-(x/th)^2)*exp(-(x/th)^2)
} in R. Thanks

Comment: Hi, it's better to post a separate question and let me know. To ask and answer questions in comments is generally frowned upon by Community.